# How to solve JQ processing as multiple dictionaries if document has an array?

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON document

```json
[
  {
    "description": "Component 1",
    "tags": [
      "abc",
      "123",
      "xyz"
    ]
  },
  {
    "description": "Component 2",
    "tags": [
      "def",
      "foo",
      "bar"
    ]
  },
  {
    "description": "Component 3",
    "tags": [
      "def"
    ]
  }
]
```

I have written below JQ filter to parse the JSON, the expected output is not to generate multiple dictionaries.

```sh
{ (.[].description):(.[].tags)}
```

After applying the filter, i get the below output with `multiple dictionaries` because of the `tags` array

```
{
  "Component 1": [
    "abc",
    "123",
    "xyz"
  ]
}
{
  "Component 1": [
    "def",
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ]
}
{
  "Component 1": [
    "def"
  ]
}
{
  "Component 2": [
    "abc",
    "123",
    "xyz"
  ]
}
{
  "Component 2": [
    "def",
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ]
}
{
  "Component 2": [
    "def"
  ]
}
{
  "Component 3": [
    "abc",
    "123",
    "xyz"
  ]
}
{
  "Component 3": [
    "def",
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ]
}
{
  "Component 3": [
    "def"
  ]
}
```

The output I am expecting is without `multiple dictionaries` as below

```
{
  "Component 1": [
    "abc",
    "123",
    "xyz"
  ]
}
{
  "Component 2": [
    "def",
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ]
}
{
  "Component 3": [
    "def"
  ]
}
```

How can I generate the above-expected output using JQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to this one

```
jq '.[] | { (.description) : .tags }'
```

in order to get rid of multiple occurences

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/SZBAZ5_Nwd)</kbd>

Comment: This is helpful. I tried implementing with `group_by`, but couldn't get it working. please advise.

```shell
group_by(.project,.status)  | map ({project: .[0].project,status: [.[0].status] | unique , desc: [{"\(.[].description)" : .[].tags }] })
```

Comment: tried interpolation without map but ending up in multiple disctionaries. 

```shell
group_by(.project,.status)  | .[] | { project: .[].project , status: .[].status , description: [{"\(.[].description)" : .[].tags}] }
```

Comment: There's no need for *string interpolation* `"\(…)"` and the `--raw-output` (or `-r`) option. Simply, also `jq '.[] | {(.description): .tags }'` will do.